# request.is_ajax return false in template

Tags: python, ajax, django

I'm trying to make conditionnal extends in a template :

```
{% extends request.is_ajax|yesno:"base_ajax.html,base.html" %}
```

In my view :

```
def new(request):
    snippet_form = SnippetForm()
    return render_to_response('new.html', {
        'snippet_form': snippet_form,
    }, context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

But request.is_ajax always return false !

If I call request.is_ajax in my view, it contains the good value.

```
def new(request):
    snippet_form = SnippetForm()
    ajax = request.is_ajax()
    return render_to_response('new.html', {
        'snippet_form': snippet_form,
        'ajax': ajax
    }, context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

And in my template :

```
{% extends ajax|yesno:"base_ajax.html,base.html" %}
```

That's works but I'd prefer use the first solution !

Any ideas ?

(I'm using the jquery load function)

Comment: Another alternative would be to make a context processor, so that you wouldn't have to do 'ajax' in any view.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do you have the 'request' context processor enabled?
The list called TEMPLATE_CONTEXT_PROCESSORS shloud have this string in it:

```
django.core.context_processors.request
```

It is off by default.